# Custom Multi-Interval Slider

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

I'm trying to make a custom generalization of the Interval Slider - one with $n$ marks to describe $n-1$ intervals. This was my attempt, but it doesn't work - it just returns itself when run:

`MultiSlider[Dynamic[xs_], n_, st_, end_, step_, inits_] := 
 LocatorPane[Table[{Dynamic[xs][[i]], 0}, {i, 1, n}], 
  Graphics[{LightGray, Thickness[0.015], Line[{{st, 0}, {end, 0}}]}]]`

How do I do this properly?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure about all the arguments, but maybe this will get you started:

```
Clear[MultiSlider];
MultiSlider[Dynamic[xs_], {st_, end_}] := 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[xs], 
  Graphics[{LightGray, Thickness[0.015], Line[{{st, 0}, {end, 0}}]}],
  {{st, 0}, {end, 0}}]

Manipulate[
 x,
 {{x, Table[{2 i, 0}, {i, 5}]}, 0, 12, MultiSlider[##] &}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can constrain the locators by specifying the range `{{st, 0}, {end, 0}}`.

---

In response to a request for 1D argument `xs`:

```
Clear[MultiSlider];
MultiSlider[Dynamic[xs_], {st_, end_}] := LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[{#, 0.} & /@ xs, (xs = #[[All, 1]]) &], 
   Graphics[{LightGray, Thickness[0.015], 
     Line[{{st, 0}, {end, 0}}]}], {{st, 0}, {end, 0}}];

Manipulate[x, {{x, Table[2 i, {i, 5}]}, 0, 12, MultiSlider[##] &}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could also use `Thread[{xs, 0.}]` to add zero y-coordinates to `xs`, among a number of alternatives, instead of `{#, 0.} & /@ xs`.

Comment: Hmm... I'd like the set `xs` to be one-dimensional, though. I tried making the function into a `DynamicModule` and adding `Dynamic[ys] = Transpose[{Dynamic[xs], Table[0, Length[Dynamic[xs]]]}];` (changing the rest of the code to fit), but that doesn't seem to work - I get a null error, or else a `Transpose` tells me that my Table is the wrong length.

Comment: @linkhyrule5 How's that? (In the updated answer)

Comment: WITCHCRAFT. That's perfect, thanks! :P

Comment: @linkhyrule5 You're welcome.